# jQuery Mobile Select Menu in Collapsible Header - Firefox doesn't work

Tags: jquery, firefox, select, header

I have a `data-role="collapsible"` with a select menu in the header.  In firefox, when you click on the select menu and choose an option, it doesn't change the option (onchange never fires).  Trying to click on the select menu a second time doesn't open the dropdown.  Other browsers work fine.
See the following as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/CbUDd/5/

```
<div data-role="page" id="the-page">
<div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right">
    <h3>Label of Header
    <select data-native-menu="true" id="theselect" style="width:100px;">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
    </select>
    </h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Any clue as to how to fix it?